# How can i make GPU process much faster than CPU process with CUDA 10.0 in Visual Studio 2017?

Tags: c++, cuda, gpu, nvidia, gpgpu

Smart developer!
I am the beginner of CUDA programming and I have a big problem with my code.

Following code is a sample code from Nvidia and I changed a little bit for showing the GPU process much faster than from CPU process. However, after compiling this code, I got a unexpected result from that CPU process is much faster than GPU process.

[This is my laptop gpu info.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fnDws.png)

This is my cuda code for Visual Studio 2017.

===========================================================================

`#define N 10`

### This is add2 function() from GPU process

```
`___global____  void add2(int *a, int *b, int *c) {`

    // GPU block from grid sector
    //int tid = blockIdx.x;     // checking the data of index  = if you 

insert min of N, you will get slow result from CPU. But if you put big number, this show much faster than CPU

// GPU thread
//int tid = threadIdx.x;    // Same result as blockIdx.x

// GPU unexpected vector    // Same result as above
int tid = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x*blockDim.x;
if (tid < N) {
    c[tid] = a[tid] + b[tid];
}
}
```

### This is add function() from CPU process

```
`void add(int *a, int *b, int *c) {

    int tid = 0;

while (tid < N) {
    c[tid] = a[tid] + b[tid];
    tid += 1;
}
}
```

### This is Main function()

```
int main() {

    // Values for time duration
         LARGE_INTEGER tFreq, tStart, tEnd;
         cudaEvent_t start, stop;
         float tms, ms;

         int a[N], b[N], c[N];  // CPU values
         int *dev_a, *dev_b, *dev_c;    // GPU values----------------------------------------------

          // Creating alloc for GPU--------------------------------------------------------------
         cudaMalloc((void**)&dev_a, N * sizeof(int));
         cudaMalloc((void**)&dev_b, N * sizeof(int));
         cudaMalloc((void**)&dev_c, N * sizeof(int));

    // Fill 'a' and 'b' from CPU
         for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
            a[i] = -i;
            b[i] = i * i;
        }

    // Copy values of CPU to GPU values----------------------------------------------------
         cudaMemcpy(dev_a, a, N * sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
         cudaMemcpy(dev_b, b, N * sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);


    //////////////////////////////////////
         QueryPerformanceFrequency(&tFreq);  // Frequency set
         QueryPerformanceCounter(&tStart);   // Time count Start

    // CPU operation
         add(a, b, c);

    //////////////////////////////////////
         QueryPerformanceCounter(&tEnd);     // TIme count End
         tms = ((tEnd.QuadPart - tStart.QuadPart) / (float)tFreq.QuadPart) * 1000;
    //////////////////////////////////////

    // show result of CPU
         cout << fixed;
         cout.precision(10);
         cout << "CPU Time=" << tms << endl << endl;

         for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
             printf("CPU calculate = %d + %d = %d\n", a[i], b[i], c[i]);
         }

         cout << endl;

    ///////////////////////////////////////
         cudaEventCreate(&start);
         cudaEventCreate(&stop);
         cudaEventRecord(start, 0);
    // GPU operatinog---------------------------------------------------------------------
         //add2 <<<N,1 >>> (dev_a, dev_b, dev_c);   // block
         //add2 << <1,N >> > (dev_a, dev_b, dev_c); // Thread
         add2 << <N/32+1, 32 >> > (dev_a, dev_b, dev_c);   // grid

    ///////////////////////////////////////
         cudaEventRecord(stop, 0);
         cudaEventSynchronize(stop);
         cudaEventElapsedTime(&ms, start, stop);
    ///////////////////////////////////////

    // show result of GPU
         cudaMemcpy(c, dev_c, N * sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
         cout << fixed;
         cout.precision(10);
         cout << "GPU Time=" << ms << endl << endl;


         for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
              printf("GPU calculate = %d + %d = %d\n", a[i], b[i], c[i]);
         }

    //Free GPU values
         cudaFree(dev_a);
         cudaFree(dev_b);
         cudaFree(dev_c);

         return 0;
}
```

[This is result of compiling this code.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vb3CX.png)

I want to make GPU process much faster than CPU process.

Comment: OP has acknowledged in cross posting [here](https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/1044297/cuda-programming-and-performance/cannot-find-a-reason-why-cpu-process-much-faster-than-gpu-process-in-simple-code/) that they can get a different comparison between CPU and GPU by making some modifications to their code.

Comment: GPU: more latency, more throughput. CPU: less latency, less throughput. So you can build an algorithm using proper building blocks of basic algorithms and a CPU or GPU(s). Are you after less latency for simple operations or less latency for many simple operations (high throughput)? GPU can give you less latency for an advanced algorithm like big 3D FFT or a brute-force nbody but less latency in element-wise multiplication/summation of a vector or matrix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The GPU is generally actually slower than the CPU for running a single operation. Additionally it takes time to send data to the GPU and read it back again.

The advantage of the GPU is it can execute many operations in parallel.

As you have defined `N` to be 10 it probably takes longer to upload and download the data than to execute on the CPU. In order to see the advantage of the GPU increase your problem size to something much larger. Ideally you want to execute a minimum of a few operations on each GPU core before you start seeing some benefit. For example with your GPU's 1280 cores you would want to execute something like 4000 operations or more at once to get the benefit of the GPU.

Comment: You mean 400 000, not 4000. 4000 would like take the same time as 10...

Comment: @talonmies it would take the same time as 10 to execute on the GPU but should take longer on the CPU. I agree that with GPU processing the more the merrier but I was giving an approximate minimum task size to start seeing some benefit.

Comment: @AlanBirtles Thank you so much to help me to understand what i don't know. By the way, I want to ask something else. Can I figure out what is minimum operations which can be faster than CPU? (This question is my curiosity to cuda programming. You can answer free or ignore it.)

Comment: The only way to figure it out is by experimentation, depends on which operations you are performing, how much data you are using, whether your compiler optimises your cpu code to use SIMD instructions and of course how fast your CPU and GPU are

Comment: @AlanBirtles OK, I will do that! And Thank you again for giving me a advice!